# Oracle cursor behaviour in trigger body

Tags: sql-server, oracle, triggers, cursor

Please help me understand the following Oracle cursor code . I am particularly confused in  the `get_geog= geography` section . What is the value of  `geography` ?  Is it taking the value of  new.geography ? Also, `c2b_rec.geolevel_id >= c2a_rec.geolevel_id` what is the difference between c2b_rec and c2a_rec here ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_name
    BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE OF geography, 
        ON tbl_name
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 

CURSOR c2(get_geog IN VARCHAR2, get_geolevel IN VARCHAR2) IS
        SELECT *
          FROM geolevels
         WHERE get_geog     = geography
           AND get_geolevel = geolevel;
    c2a_rec c2%ROWTYPE;
    c2b_rec c2%ROWTYPE;

IF c2b_rec.geolevel_id >= c2a_rec.geolevel_id THEN
some code
```

Comment: I understood the code you provided as example 
@zaratustra but not the code that I have initially posted. My questions still are on `c2b_rec.geolevel_id >= c2a_rec.geolevel_id` and `WHERE get_geog     = geography` . There is no `open` cursor or fetch cursor in the code .

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
CURSOR c2(get_geog IN VARCHAR2, get_geolevel IN VARCHAR2) 
IS
SELECT *
  FROM geolevels
 WHERE get_geog = geography
   AND get_geolevel = geolevel;
```

means that you declare a new cursor that is based on the result set of its `SELECT` statement. Since you didn't show us other variables I can conclude that `geography` and `geolevel` are fields of the `geolevels` table. `get_geog` and `get_geolevel` are the parameters of the cursor.

This lines:

```
c2a_rec c2%ROWTYPE;
c2b_rec c2%ROWTYPE;
```

declare two variables that will be available for fetching data from the cursor.

Before this line:

```
IF c2b_rec.geolevel_id >= c2a_rec.geolevel_id THEN
```

you have to have a part where the cursor is opened and fetched. Something like this:

```
OPEN c2('one', 'two');
fetch c2 into c2a_rec;
fetch c2 into c2b_rec;
```

When you fetch the cursor you extract rows from the result set that the select statement returns. So the `c2a_rec` variable will have the first rows of the result set and the `c2b_rec` variable will have the second rows of the result set. Then you compare the values of the `geolevel_id` fields of the cursors with this line:

```
IF c2b_rec.geolevel_id >= c2a_rec.geolevel_id THEN
```

So if you don't know how to use parametrized cursors look at this:

```
create table t1 (
  id number(10)
);
create table t2 (
  id number(10)
);
create OR REPLACE trigger t1_trg 
after insert
on t1
for each row
declare
  cursor c1 (p_id NUMBER)
  is
    select id
      from t2
     where id = p_id
  ;
  c1_row c1%ROWTYPE;
begin
  open c1(1);
  fetch c1 into c1_row;
  IF c1%FOUND
  THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(c1_row.id);
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('There is not such value');
  END IF;
  close c1;
END t1_trg;

INSERT INTO t1 values (1);

There is not such value

1 row(s) inserted.

INSERT INTO t2 values (1);

1 row(s) inserted.

INSERT INTO t1 values (2);

1

1 row(s) inserted.
```

As you can see I passed the value 1 when I opened the cursor and this value was used when the cursor got opened.

Comment: Thanks for this . geography and geolevel are fields present in geolevel table but get_geog and get_geolevel are CURSOR variables,  I thought . So , `SELECT *
  FROM geolevels
 WHERE get_geog = geography
   AND get_geolevel = geolevel;` Can return more than one matched row and `c2a_rec c2%ROWTYPE;` and `c2b_rec c2%ROWTYPE;` will hold the first and second row from the geolevel table ? But these two vars are not present in the `tbl_name` that the trigger is on so where exactly it is getting the values from ?

Comment: I didn't understand you. How can get_geog and get_geolevel be cursor variables if you didn't show any other cursors except c2?

Comment: Apologies , but I am new to cursors as have avoided it in SQL Server at all costs .I thought they are cursor variables because of this line,  `CURSOR c2(l_geography IN VARCHAR2, l_geolevel_name IN VARCHAR2)` ?

Comment: ok, now I see, your cursor has parameters, so get_geog and get_geolevel are parameters of the cursor. So when you open it you have to pass parameters: like `open c2('first', 'second');` But what is your question?

Comment: Yes correct , my question is , the trigger is written on `tbl_name` and it has no geography column so when the cursor is matching the values of geoghraphty and geolevel , where is it getting the value to match from ? `WHERE get_geog = geography    AND get_geolevel = geolevel`

Comment: Also ,OPEN c2('one', 'two');
`fetch c2 into c2a_rec; fetch c2 into c2b_rec;` is not in the code so how is c2b_rec and c2a_rec different to each other  `c2b_rec.geolevel_id >= c2a_rec.geolevel_id`